# Cannot call close after closing override

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to have a single instance of the window, so I wrote this code:

```
public static Settings Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (AppWindow == null)
        {
            AppWindow = new Settings();
            //attach the event handler
            AppWindow.Closing += AppWindow_Closing;
        }
        return AppWindow;
    }
}

private static async void AppWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;

    //call the async method
    bool close = await AppWindow.CheckSettings();
    if (close)
    {
        AppWindow win = (AppWindow)sender;
        //detach the event handler
        AppWindow.Closing -= AppWindow_Closing;
        //...and close the window immediately
        win.Close();
        AppWindow = null;
    }
}
```

as you can see I did an override of the closing event, inside it I call `CheckSettings()` which has this structure:

```
private async Task<bool> CheckSettings()
{
     MessageDialogResult result =
                    await this.ShowMessageAsync(Lang.Line("attention", dict), Lang.Line("unsavedChanges", dict),
                    MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative, dialogSettings);

     if(result == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative)
         return true;
     else
         return false;
}
```

I need to wait the result from the `MahApp` method `ShowMessageAsync()`, so I cancelled the close event in the closing override.

Unfortunately this code win.Close() return an exception:

> cannot set visibility or call show or showdialog after window has closed

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried simply setting `e.Cancel = false;` if `close` is `true`? (Or not setting it to begin with)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer not working, for the moment I managed setting the visibility instead of close, dont know why